# Connect data to highcharts javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, highcharts

I have some data I want to connect to my highcharts.

So far I get data in my z3s.js

```
KpiChartTrendForZxController = function($scope, $http, LocationService) {
  var GetKpiChartTrendForZx, dates;
  GetKpiChartTrendForZx = function(containerId) {
    var serviceUrl;
    serviceUrl = iSee.ServiceLocator.KpiChartTrendZxForContainer(containerId);
    return $http.get(serviceUrl).success(function(data) {
      return $scope.trendForZx = data;
    });
  };
```

My data looks like :
series: [
    {
      name: "Z3 from ZB - Sum",
      data: [["04/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["05/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["06/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["07/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["08/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["09/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["10/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["11/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["12/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["13/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["14/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["15/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["16/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["17/04/2013 08:00", 5], ["18/04/2013 08:00", 5]]

How can I add them to my series?
data:
Value[i]: name[i], data[i]

data[i]: Time[j],Values[j]

Thanks

Comment: link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbsvbs/dLgCb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
var dateEndLabel, dateStartLabel, i, j, lastDate, seriesData, x, y;
  i = 0;
  seriesData = new Array();
  lastDate = data[i].Values.length - 1;
  dateStartLabel = data[i].Values[0].Time;
  dateEndLabel = data[i].Values[lastDate].Time;
  while (i < data.length) {
    seriesData[i] = [];
    j = 0;
    x = [];
    y = [];
    while (j < data[i].Values.length) {
      x = data[i].Values[j].Time;
      y = data[i].Values[j].Value;
      seriesData[i].push([x, y]);
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
```

Then added them to my highchart series:

```
 series: [
      {
        name: data[0].Name,
        data: seriesData[0]
      }, {
        name: data[1].Name,
        data: seriesData[1]
      }, {
        name: data[2].Name,
        data: seriesData[2]
      }, {
        name: data[3].Name,
        data: seriesData[3]
      }, {
        name: data[4].Name,
        data: seriesData[4]
      }, {
        name: data[5].Name,
        data: seriesData[5]
      }
    ],
```

My issue is solved now, but I think I could shrink my code to a smaller one in series. Anyway it works now and I have another callenges in highcharts :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be timestamp, in other words time in miliseconds. So instead of this

```
 ["04/04/2013 08:00", 5],
```

It should be

```
 [Date.UTC(2014,3,4,8), 5],
```

Which returns corret format.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. My date is a string. My problem is I need to push data to my xaxis and yaxis in my highchart. I only get the last data in my chart. How can I push all data?